# How to run a command after a delay at login with .bashrc

Tags: command-line, bashrc

I'm trying to run a command line on `.bashrc` after 20 seconds so I'm doing

```
sleep 20 && cp text1.txt text2.txt
```

But the system will not start until the 20 seconds go by, and then it will start.
Is there anyway the system can start and then execute after 20 seconds the command script?

Comment: Do you want a command to run 20 seconds after you log in? It may be simpler to just use the "autostart" feature of whatever desktop you are using.

Comment: What is your initial problem? Why do you need to `cp` a txt file to another, what do you wait 20 seconds for ? Is this an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the command in the background using "&"

```
sleep 20 && cp text1.txt text2.txt &
```

The shell job ID (surrounded with brackets) and process ID will be printed on the terminal:

**[1] 25177**

To suppress the stdout and stderr messages use the following syntax:

```
sleep 20 && cp text1.txt text2.txt > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

`> /dev/null 2>&1` means redirect stdout to `/dev/null` and stderr to stdout